# Change sections title color in didSelectRow

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview, uitableviewsectionheader

After tapping on cell in particular section I want to change text color for title label in custom headerView.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        switch viewModel?.sections[indexPath.section].cellType {
        case .selectionCell:
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CheckboxesTableViewCell
            guard let checkboxOption = viewModel?.sections[indexPath.section].checkboxOptions?[indexPath.row] else { return }
            checkboxOption.isSelected = !checkboxOption.isSelected
            cell?.update(viewModel: checkboxOption)
            
            // place where I should change text color for custom header
            // let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: QuestionaryTableViewHeader

        case .textCell:
            debugPrint("Text field tapp")
        case .none:
            break
        }
    }
```

Any help...

[image]

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: headerView.titleLabel.textColor = .red not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `headerView(forSection:`

```
if let headerView = tableView.headerView(forSection:indexPath.section) as? QuestionaryTableViewHeader {
   headerView.titleLabel.textColor = .red  
}
```